# XML Sitemap and RSS / Atom feeds extension

Tags: extensions, sitemaps, rss

could someone recommend me a Magento extension which would be capable of generating both - XML Sitemaps and RSS (or Atom) feeds and fully comply with recently published Google's best practices for XML Sitemaps and RSS/Atom feeds:

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/10/best-practices-for-xml-sitemaps-rssatom.html

Additionally, the extension should have options of splitting generated XML sitemaps, pinging search engines and would respect canonical versions only (meaning that only those should be included in generated files). These are the main requirements, at this moment.

I'd consider all options as my own attempts to find such extension (or even combination of several) weren't successful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some time went over it, so I'm not sure whether this answer is still current. Could you let us know if you found anything on Magento Connect or GitHub? Or did you find another solution for this?